# Sort Table View by Ui Label Name

Tags: swift, uitableview, sorting

I have a table view that the user adds recipes too and right now it just sorts based on the order they add the recipes. I would like to have the table view sort by the Recipe Name (UILabel) A-> Z. Not sure what code might be helpful but below is the Data Class I have set up and the UI Label outlet is named recipeNameLabel in UITableViewCell.

```
class Recipe: NSObject, NSCoding {

    var name: String
    var servings: String
    var category: String
    var prepTime: String
    var cookTime: String
    var source: String
    var sourceURL: String
    var photo: UIImage?
}
```

I called this in UITableView to retrieve the data model:

```
var recipes2 = Recipe()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to sort the array you are using as your data source.
Assuming you have an array of `Recipe`s:

```
var recipes = [Recipe]()
```

You could use `sort` to sort the recipes by their `name` property:

```
recipes = recipes.sort({ current, next in 
    return current.name < next.name
})
```

Comment: that worked great...only question is it only works when the app is loaded. If the user is in the app and adds a new recipe, it just goes to the bottom. Is there an Update Table View command I can initiate to re-sort when a new recipe is added?

Comment: Also, I implemented the above code in viewDidLoad. Is that right?

Comment: You can call `reloadData()` for your `UITableView` to refresh its data after re-sorting it.